# How to get gatsbyImageData to work with createSchemaCustomization

Tags: gatsby

I have this is in my **gatsby-node.js**..

```
interface Vacancy {
jobImage: {
    gatsbyImageData: any;
    title: string;
    description: string;
}};

const vacancyQueryResult = await graphql<QueryResult>(`
query VacancyQuery {
    allContentfulVacancy {
        edges {
          node {
            jobImage {
                gatsbyImageData
                title
                description
            }}}}});
```

i need to the add the **gatsbyImageData** to my `createSchemaCustomization` function for `createPages`..

how can i fix this?